# New user posts 20+ times within 10 minutes?

Tags: discussion

How is it possible for a new user to post 20+ questions, with mostly the same content, within 10 minutes, on the same day the account was created? How is there no throttling? How do these posts remain open for more than half an hour, even though their content is not at all related to code review?

This is one of the posts:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/285613/unban-kemono-pantsu-now-she-has-gotten-her-224-accounts-on-99-platforms-banned

Comment: "How is it possible for a new user to post 20+ questions" answering the question here would result in giving users who misuse systems information to bypass systems. If you ask "How is there no throttling?" on MSE you'll likely make a bigger splash and get SE to actually look at the question at hand. "How do these posts remain open for more than half an hour, even though their content is not at all related to code review?" Because people aren't around to handle the posts. The posts are handled now.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Thanks for the work you do. I didn’t mean to be disparaging, I was just really surprised to see that mess on the front page.

Comment: No problem, I didn't see any reason to interpret what you said as "disparaging".

Comment: This is a known troublemaker that's usually caught by volunteer moderators. Some of those are on strike. The rest of the network gets these too and it's not new. What's new is they usually disappear within minutes and now they don't.